# css,html: allowed properties for html elements, good reference site

Tags: html, css

Some elements like tr don't seem to support all the basic css properties.   For example, as far as I can tell, doing something like:

```
 <tr style="padding-top: 250px;">
```

has no effect.  Can you please give me a good link for a site explaining allowed properties by element type?   And if you have a comment on the above limitation please do share too.

Comment: I think that the `display` property controlls if `padding` can be applied to an element, not the element itself. So you basically need to check what combinations of css properties are allowed.

Comment: Thanks @Emil H, appreciate it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can search it in [Mozilla Developer Network (**MDN**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/).

For example, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

> **Applies to:** all elements except `table-row-group`, `table-header-group`, `table-footer-group`, `table-row`, `table-column-group` and `table-column`

`<tr>` is (by default) a `table-row`, so `padding` does nothing.

Note that it's not possible to make a list of allowed properties of each element type because allowed properties don't depend only on the element type.

For example, a `<div>` with `display:table-row` ignores `padding` property ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cuY2g/)).

Comment: Thanks but I want to look up an element like tr or audio, and see the list of supported styles/properties.

Comment: @Ray But it doesn't always depend on the element type. For example, a `<div>` with `display:table-row` can't have padding.

Comment: So you're saying they can't make a reference like the one I'm looking for?

Comment: @Ray Yes, it's not possible to make a list of allowed properties of each element type because allowed properties don't depend only on the element type.

Comment: So @Oriol I added padding-top to one td element hoping it would affect the entire row, but it did not.  How do you put in spacing between table rows?

Comment: @Ray You can use [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to put the `padding-top` on the `<td></td>` or `<th>` element, not the `<tr>`.

Block elements like `<div>` support padding and margins, whereas inline elements such as `<span>` do not.

`<tr>` behaves like an inline element (though it technically isn't), and a padding can easily be added to a table row, once you replace your code with

```
<tr style="padding-top: 250px; display: block;">
```

or if you use

```
tr { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that the tr is an inline element.  When I made it into a block element other parts of the table got screwy -- e.g. the columns no longer lined up as before.   So do I have to put padding on each td, or only one?  Is this the best way to put space in between rows?

Comment: You'll only have to put padding on one td.

Comment: Yes, I meant td. Also you might want to change `display: block;` to `display: block-inline;`

Comment: @desbest It's `display: inline-block`, not `block-inline`

Comment: @desbest altering the display messes up the columns at least in my table.  When I added padding-top to just one td, it didn't affect the whole table.